# Different ways of using UART

Tags: uart, buffer, beaglebone-black, fifo, debian

What is the difference when you send/receive data via Linux serial device file like ttyS3 and when you directly read/write from/to UART FIFO buffers? What situation is more safe and better?

How device file ttyS and UART FIFO buffers are connected, how do they communicate?

Will Linux have a problem if we directly read/write from FIFO buffers, instead of using drivers made for that purpose?

Comment: Through the serial driver.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: When I read data from device file (communicating with my GSM module) I am receiving what I need, but it somehow repeats data and reading me data that was received earlier, maybe it is a problem in linux UART device driver, so that file is not correctly erased or it is a problem with FIFO buffers, I dont know. @CL.

Comment: You should use the OS driver whenever possible, because it makes your software independent of the actual hardware (USB-serial converter? Bluethooth remote serial interface?). Use the hardware directly only when you realy realy have to.

Comment: The chance that such a problem is in the device drivers is not zero, but I would worry about a meteorite strike first.

Comment: You can look into the source of kernel how it is done. There is a specific hardware driver for your platform in /drivers/tty/serial

Comment: It's possible your reading the whole of the input buffer every time you call the reading function. It might be there is an alternate function that only delivers new data and not the whole input buffer. Could even be a parameter is needed when calling the read function to get just new data. I saw this only once long ago, apparently this allows the calling function to scan a chunk of data to pattern match the beginning of a valid data packet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device driver itself works by ultimately by just writing to the UART FIFO and control registers.

The main reason why you typically would want to use the driver rather than writing to the UART directly is because the driver gives you a layer of abstraction. It lets you treat that UART like other UARTs, and even sometimes like any other file. You do not need to know which bit is the Data Ready Bit and what the divisor registers are for the UART you happened to be using since the driver makes all UARTs look pretty much the same. Additionally, the driver typically gives you a nice big managed buffer on top of the FIFOs and handles all the interrupts, which requires writing some specialized code under Linux.

That said, there are times when writing directly to the UART can give you control that is not available though the driver. Here is a project where I skip the Linux device driver on a Raspberry PI and go directly to the UART to be able to generate signals for a WS2812B...

http://wp.josh.com/2014/09/03/inside-neouart-tricking-a-serial-port-into-being-a-signal-generator/

This would not be possible to do via the driver because it depends on some quirks of the specific UART, along with some state transitions that there is no way to reliably get the driver to do in the right order.

In cases where you do decide to write directly to the UART, it is probably a good idea to disable the driver to avoid conflicts. For example, if you are trying to read bytes out of the FIFO via your userspace program, it is likely that the driver will also be reading bytes and will likely win because it gets gets triggered off of interrupts. Similarly, you might change some register directly while the driver assumes that register will stay set to whatever it initialized it to (or vice versa).